# Is My Kentia Palm Unhappy?

Tags: diagnosis, palm

We bought this plant 2-3 months ago. It is in a place without direct light, and the temperature in the room is 27/30 degrees with a humidity 50-70%.

We water with drinking water every 2 weeks.
We didn't change the pot from the shop, but set it into a bigger one.
We don't know what happening :(
Can you help please ?

[image]

Comment: Your plant is healthy. Why not water more often and give it more light, please?

Answer (score 0):

Palms like Sandy soils, virtually ALl palms grow in sandy substrate exception to subtropical ones in acidic wetlands like Sabals and palmetto. Best guess if your palm is droopy, a little warmth is in order.
An ultra clear plastic bag. Otherwise known as CLear greenhouse or ghetto greenhouse. Mist the leaves to allow a humid environment and then remove from time to time.
[image]

In fairness palms like sandier, well drained soils. Lastly potassium and magnesium deficiencies kill many palm growers babies. Best guess is Palm fertilizer, if you don't have it, use a citrus fertilizer which has all micronutrients. Palms respond best to a fertilizer with the N-P-K ratio of 3-1-3 or 3-1-2 or 12-4-12 or 16-4-25. In any case. Kentias placed in darker corners with little natural light tend to look leggy and grow very slowly, best to leave roots alone except when repotting. Lastly let it dry between waterings do not keep the soil inundated. Give it the poke test.... stick your finger in soil up to an inch. If it's wet/watery and brown you're overwatering. Underlying soil should be soft and fibery damp, top a little dry.